# Passing data to Razor View in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET and trying some basic things like passing hard-coded data to Razor views.

I have a simple class in a model:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

In my CustomersController, I have this code: Basically, I'm just making an enumerable list of hard-coded customers, doing a simple get method and calling that method in the get route at /customers

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var customers = GetCustomers();

            return View(customers);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Peter Parker"
                },

                new Customer
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Eddie Brock"
                },

                new Customer
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Mary Jane"
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

In my Razor view, I bring in the model and try to loop through the customers and print them in a list. Not sure what I'm doing wrong as the intellense won't bring up anything. I can't say like @customer.Name in the li.And if I hover over the Model.Customer in the @foreach block, it says that there's no definition of customer.

```
@model Vidly.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<ul>
    @foreach(var customer in Model.Customers)
    {
        <li>@customer</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetCustomers()` method returns a **collection** of `Customer` objects and you are passing that collection to the view. So your view should be strongly typed to the collection `Customer` objects. Your current code says it expects a single Customer object.

Change it to be strongly typed to a collection of `Customer` objects, and then inside your view, you may loop the `Model`, which is a collection (*you can iterate through a collection*).

```
@model List<Vidly.Models.Customer>    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<ul>
    @foreach(var customer in Model)
    {
        <li>@customer.Id</li>
        <li>@customer.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```